# Create dataset from dataframe so that each attribute combination have same number of positive/negative samples

Tags: python, pandas

## Problem

Now I have a dataset that looks like

```
     attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5  attr6  attr7  attr8  attr9  attr10  y
0        0      0      1      1      1      0      0      0      1       1  1
1        0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0       0  1
2        1      0      0      1      1      0      1      0      0       1  1
3        1      0      1      0      0      1      1      0      1       1  1
4        0      1      1      1      1      1      0      0      0       1  1
```

which is produced by

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1000, 11)), 
                  columns=["attr"+str(i+1) for i in range(10)] + ["y"])
```

Now I would like to have a new dataset so that each combination of `attr1` through `attr10` will have exactly same number of positive and negative samples. For example `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0)` will have 100 positive and negative samples, `(0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 1)` will also have 100 positive and negative samples, etc.

Since there will be 1024 different combinations, enumeration is not possible. I am wondering if there is some smart way to do this.

Comment: Can you please explain the expected output more? Sorry I am not able to understand.

Comment: Let me make the setting simpler. Say if I have two attributes `attr1` and `attr2` and they both take value 0 and 1. Then there are four different combinations `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)` and `(1, 1)`. The goal is to let each combination sample same number of positive and negative samples from original dataset, which is potentially imbalanced with respect these combinations.